# How to convert lines to numbered list?

Tags: macro, text-generation, enumerate

I've few lines (or paragraph if easier - <kbd>{</kbd>, <kbd>}</kbd>) which I would like to convert to numbered/ordered list, in example:

```
Item one
Item two
Item three
```

into:

```
1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three
```

I would assume that it needs to be done either by macro or some plugin. But any method would be ok.

Comment: So I've added in this case [tag:unix] as I'm on OSX, as I'm not limiting to pure vim, especially on Windows. So in this case it's not duplicate. Then Unix commands are welcomed.

Comment: The other answer covers many different sort of answers; including Vim-only and UNIX-only. Actually, the UNIX-only will also work on windows if you have msysgit or cygwin installed. Unless there's a compelling reason why none of the answers work for you, I see no reason to add another question (and thus, this is a duplicate).